# Rewrite rule for a zf2 app in a subfolder

Tags: php, .htaccess, zend-framework2

I have a domain with several applications, URLS are :

```
www.domain.com/
www.domain.com/app1/
www.domain.com/app2/
www.domain.com/app3/
www.domain.com/app4/
```

app3 is a zf2 application, so my root tree is something like :

```
/
/app1/
/app2/
/app3/
/app3/config/
/app3/data/
/app3/module/
/app3/public/
/app3/vendor/
/app4/
```

**I do not want to use subdomains for the zf2 app.**

But the app3 root URL must redirect to the public subfolder, as it is a zf2 app. So in /app3/ I wrote an htaccess file to redirect to public folder :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/app3/public
RewriteRule (.*) /app3/public/$1 [L]
```

But My app3 (url www.domain.com/app3/) always displays 404 error, saying route don't exists. The URL helpers in my layout makes urls likes http://www.domain.com/myroute instead of http://www.domain.com/app3/myroute

So I guess there is a route issue : how to say this zf2 application that it is located in a subfolder /app3/ ? *Remember, I don't want to use subdmains...* Is there something I can do in my .htaccess, or in my zf2 application ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't found any simple solution to locate a ZF2 app in a subfolder without using subdomains or hacking the route system.

**The easiest way is to run ZF2 as root application**.

And if other applications are not designed to run in subfolders, user subdomains. For information, this is what I've done :

```
www.domain.com/        => is now a part of /app4/
www.domain.com/app1/   => no change,       /app1/
www.domain.com/app2/   => no change,       /app2/
www.domain.com/app3/   => ZF2 app is now   /      => merged with my root pages. I added an app3 route to keep the old urls compatibles with the new app...
www.domain.com/app4/   => no change,       /app4/
```